# How to create factory in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had created a factory in angular but i am  getting the following  error

```
Unknown provider:
```

Here is the factory:

```
app.factory("getFoo", function($scope){
    return {
       getCommi: function(val,id){
          var array = ["hello","world"];
          return array;
       }
     } 
});
```

The controller is:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','getFoo',function($scope,getFoo){
   $scope.myArr = getFoo.getCommi(4,1);
}])
```

What can I have to do for  fix this? I just don't see any problem.

Comment: Have you injected your factory in the controller?

Comment: Have you added factory to your module (e.g. `angular.module('app')`)?

Comment: i have edit the controller look like. i didn't add factory to my module

Comment: do not inject `$scope` to `getFoo`

Comment: thanks  artur grzesiak, I removed the $scope from the factory and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of scope and your factory injection should be like below

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getFoo) {
   $scope.myArr = getFoo.getCommi(4,1);
  
});

app.factory('getFoo', function () {
  return {
       getCommi: function(val,id){
          var array = ["hello","world"];
          return array;
       }
     } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>{{myArr}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove `$scope` from factory.

[working fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28672/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove $scope from your factory and add factory "getFoo" as a dependency in your app's run module like this:

app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'getFoo', function($rootScope, $location, getFoo) {

}]);

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **$scope** from the factory.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.factory("getFoo", function(){
    return {
       getCommi: function(val,id){
          var array = ["hello","world"];
          return array;
       }
    } 
});

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','getFoo',function($scope,getFoo){
   $scope.myArr = getFoo.getCommi(4,1);

}])
```